# When overloading methods in C++, is it possible to consider the equal operator and assign the return value to another class instance?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

Is it possible to have in a class a method that modifies its own class instance, but by overloading it can also modify another class instance or even create a new one, if for example the equal sign is used? Or do I need to overload the operator in a special way?

Something like this:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass() {};
    MyClass(int x): number(x) {};

    void increaseNumber(){
        number++;
    }

    MyClass increaseNumber() const{
        MyClass tempObj(this->number);
        tempObj.number++
        return tempObj;
    }
private:
    int number = 0;
}


int main(){
    MyClass a(10);
    
    a.increaseNumber();             // -> a.number == 11
    MyClass b = a.increaseNumber()  // -> b.number == 12   ???
}
```

Comment: No. Your code will increase `a` and create `b` as copy of `a` (after it was increased). What would be the benefit of such overloading, when you can simply do `b.increaseNumber();`?

Comment: Overloads are allowed only if types of arguments are different. overload determines return type not vice versa!

Comment: I suspect that this is [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is your actual goal? What are you trying to achieve? Stop describing how you trying to achieve this.

Comment: Sure, just pass the instance by reference to the function, then anything is fair game.

Comment: `MyClass(const MyClass& rhs) : number(rhs.number + 1) {}`?

Comment: An operator overload can do anything any other class method can do, that takes the same parameters and has the same `const`-qualification. Other than that, your question is unclear. What does "the equals sign is used" mean?

Comment: `a = a.increaseNumber()` seems to be the trivial solution.

Comment: `MyClass b = ..` uses constructor, not assignment.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. In this example, my goal would be to copy the number from a to b including the increasement.

Answer (score 0):

First I hope I understood your question correctly, please correct me if you don't mean this. The overload can be done as long as the signature is changed. in your code the signature is changed by const key word , also return type. I can give you an example of overloading equal sign twice in the same class as follow:

the first implementation is used as default copy, you copy the rhs to the lhs, while the second implementation move the data without copying.

```
class Factor {
    int _n = 0;
    int _d = 1;        
    
public:
    Factor & operator = (const Factor &);
    Factor & operator = (Factor &&) noexcept;

Factor & Factor::operator = ( const Factor & rhs ) {
    message("op =");
    if( this != &rhs ) {
        _n = rhs.numerator();
        _d = rhs.denominator();
    }
    return *this;
}

Factor & Factor::operator = ( Factor && rhs ) noexcept {
    message("op move =");
    if ( this != &rhs ) {
        _n = std::move(rhs._n);
        _d = std::move(rhs._d);
        rhs.reset();
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, was not exactly what I needed, but good to know!

Comment: more welcome, I saw the question mark on this  b.number == 12   ???, simply you had used increaseNumber() twice after number was 10 at a instantiation. First you used void method on a, then you used myclass method in your last line, then you did the increment twice.

Answer (score 0):

As a conclusion for me and as an answer to my own question:

1. You cannot overload a method by changing the return type but keeping
   the same parameters. So for this purpose you have to define a method
   with a different name.
2. If a class instance is initialized with another already existing
   class instance and the equal sign, the (copy?) constructor is called and not
   the assignment operator. e.g.:

> ```
> MyClass a(10);
> MyClass b = a;
> ```